# Learn to Program (Chris Pine) Answer explanation

Tags: ruby

Chapter 7, first exercise at the end of the chapter (e-book) --> https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_07.html

I was able to get the code, but only once I set a variable and set it equal to something. I don't really understand why and would appreciate any explanation as to why you have to do this.

Here's my code:

```
puts "Tell me some of your favorite words-- one at a time, please!"

fave_words = []

word = '0'

while word != ''
     word = gets.chomp
     fave_words.push word
end

puts "Here are a few of your favorite words..."
puts fave_words.join(' ')
puts "Now in alphabetical order..."
puts fave_words.sort
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why I needed to set word equal to something (word = '0')

Comment: Without it, you would receive a `NameError` complaining that you are referencing an ``undefined local variable or method `word'``

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the loop to work (and to get into it for the first time mainly) is the word having a value different than an empty string. So it doesn't matter if you make it `word = '0'` or `word ='any other string'`. As long as you set it to something different than `''` the loop clause will evaluate to `true` and the loop will start. As long as you provide a non empty input to it it will keep in the loop because the clause will remain evaluating to `true`.

Actually you don't even need to declare a variable outside of the loop. You could just do something like:

```
while true
   word = gets.chomp
   break if word.empty?
   fave_words.push word
end
```

So the loop starts immediately because `eval(true)` is truth. The loop will keep going until your input is an empty string, condition in which we break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`word` is always the input from the user and as long as it's a non-empty string the `while` loop functions. In order to get the ball rolling `word` is defined outside of the loop and set to a non-empty string, thus the loop executes.

When the user inputs nothing by pressing `enter` alone, the `while` loop condition fails and the loops ceases.